# Error: could not find or load main class Hello

Tags: java

I write simple java program in notepad and try to run the program using cmd but got the **"Error: could not find or load main class Hello"**.

I able to run program in eclipse but when i try to run using cmd then i face this problem.

```
class Hello
{
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
         System.out.println("Hello Parth...");
     }
}
```

Comment: Have you compiled using `javac` before running the `java` command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Comment: @Shashwat I already compiled my code. I have Hello.class file in my folder.

Comment: @RamanSahasi thank you but i read all answers and try all possible way but still i got this error.

Comment: @Squiddie String args[] = String[] args.

Comment: How are you invoking Java and in which directory are you at that point?

Comment: @ParthPatel Please give some details, otherwise this would be closed as a duplicate of the linked question

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt File Hello.java is in c:\Users\parth\Desktop\java

Comment: @ParthPatel Thanks, but that wasn't what I was asking.

Comment: @Shashwat I already write comment regarding this. I already read all the answers of similar questions.

Comment: @ParthPatel Are you sure you are at the same directory where the class is located ? If using **windows** you can hold`shift` and right click on any empty space on the folder, and choose **open command window here** and then try executing, with the `java` command

Comment: @Shashwat i'm in the same directory and run from where the class file is located.

Answer (score 1):

After all i found the answer.

I set Path manually. So i remove CLASSPATH, CATALINA_HOME, CATALINA, JAVA_HOME after that i restart my computer.

Finally my program run.

If any one face this problem then please try my way.